# Ijetty deployed war, need ijetty's context

Tags: android, ijetty

I am using ijetty and I have a war deployed on it. One service it provides it to send emails out from the phone remotely. The recipients/subject/body are all POSTed to the server and I want to send them out of the phone.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app) method and it send the mail fine but I need the users credentials. Even if I could just get the email and then the user posted the password that would be fine but to do this I need to use

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
```

The problem is that I do not know how to get ijetty's context so that I can get the accounts.

If anyone can help or provide some other direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got an awnser from the ijetty mailing list and here it is,

```
android.content.ContentResolver resolver =
(android.content.ContentResolver)getServletContext().getAttribute("org.mortbay.ijetty.contentResolver");
android.content.Context androidContext =
(android.content.Context)getServletContext().getAttribute("org.mortbay.ijetty.context");
```

With these 2 objects you should be able to do what you want. Alternatively,
you could always subclass i-jetty to provide access to more android objects.